# I need XML format(request) for giving me details about which window opened?

Tags: xml, events, quickbooks, qbxml

Is there any XML format for finding which window currently opened?
 Like sending request in XML format and get UI event details in response.
 I try with this "UIEventSubscriptionAddRq" XML element but they not giving any window/UI event details.
 I finding for getting details with "IEventsMsgSet" object of "QBFC7LIB" dll.

Thanks,

Comment: No, there is nothing that will do this.

Answer (score 1):

QuickBooks does not provide API call that will give you this information. It's not possible.